# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass (is email necessary in the code below)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is at the error screen at localhost:3000 as I run the rails server.

[image]

Comment: Here, your current_user object is nil. that's why you are getting that error. add your controller code here

Comment: I think, you are not logged in and hence you get current_user object nil so try add authenticate_user before_filter for this action and try access this page after signing/logged in. So you will get current_user object as logged in user and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether `user signed in` and then add those links as below:

If you are using `devise`,

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><%= link_to current_user.email, "#" %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

If you not using `devise` then check:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><%= link_to current_user.email, "#" %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm using devise and I tried your solution, yet it gives the same error of undefined method 'email' :-( but if I remove my lines and only keep yours, it does show up the login page but won't don anything..

Comment: It may be because, you have given before_action :authenticate_user! In application controller. So, if user not signed in it redirects to the login page.

Comment: request_token = client.request_token(:oauth_callback => "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/oauth_account")

Comment: Now it gives error on the above line (OAuth::Problem in LinkedinController#generate_linkedin_oauth_url )

Comment: My webpage does take the login but does nothing, does not log in to the linkedin profile which I wanna log into and fetch the profile picture. But when I sign up and then select connect to linkedin then the above mentioned lines pop_up :-/

Answer (score 0):

> Controller filters and helpers

`Devise` will create some helpers to use inside your controllers and views. To set up a controller with user authentication, just add this before_action (**assuming your devise model is** '`User`'):

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

> For Rails 5

Note that `protect_from_forgery` is no longer prepended to the `before_action` chain, so if you have set `authenticate_user` before `protect_from_forgery`, your request will result in "**Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.**" To resolve this, either change the order in which you call them, or use protect_from_forgery prepend: true.

[Reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)